# Turning a second order ODE into a system of first order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the second order ODE
\begin{equation}
    \left(
        \frac{y'}{x^2\rho}
    \right)'
    +
    \lambda \frac{c\,\rho}{x^2P}\, y
    =
    0
\end{equation}
I think the corresponding first-order system is
\begin{align}
y'_1 &= x^2\rho\, y_2\\
y'_2 &= -\lambda \frac{c\rho}{x^2 P} \, y_1
\end{align}
but I am not sure. How can I tell?

Comment: To avoid mistakes, in general, the most easy is always to let $y_1=y$, $y_2=y'$. You picked $y_2=y'/(x^2\rho)$, which is also fine and arguably results in cleaner equations!